# Cannot install APK file in real Android phone/

Tags: android, installation, apk

I cannot install apk file into my LG V10 while The app run perfect on the Android Emulator. I already check the Unknown Source, I use code to prevent dimming
    // prevent screen Dimming

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

I choose the Build Variant is Debug. It got error if I choose Release:

```
Error: Fragments should be static such that they can be re-instantiated by the system, and anonymous classes are not static [ValidFragment]
```

Here is my Gradle:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "quiz"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

The FragmentActivity.java It is kind of long. So I hope you guys read all it.

I put it in the Google docs. I try 10 minutes to put it as code, but It appears so many errors.

[Fragment file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5JYElu2jy0WZmlFZVlwZWRHWjA/view?usp=sharing)

Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Comment: you have an issue with the way your wrote your fragment (ValidFragment) can you post the code for this class?

Comment: I just put my Fragment code on the Google drive. Can you take a look and help me solve this probelm? Thanks.

Comment: Put it in your question

Comment: I can't. I have errors when I post it here. I don't know why. I spend 10 minutes but it still stay errors

Answer (score -1):

It seems that some issue with fragment, and code to be reviewed in order to make sure what error is.

Possible solution
Change the app built variants to release from debug.
Change version code and version name if you are updating the app check on version name is changed.

First connect you LG smartphone and see whether it is connected to Android studio.

This type of errors occurred due to miss configured development environment or your smartphone doesn't support the app.

If it runs on emulator then it should also run in your app with out any issues.

Comment: Sadly running in emulators does not guarantee running on physical devices.  The most recent example is Samsung adding display scaling code in their Android release which affects drag and drop functionality because physical screen locations are modified at the OS level.

Comment: Yeah, I built some other apps and they worked well with my LG V10. Only this apps had this problem.